# How to load Classes from a Jar

Tags: java

So I want to include into a project of me a plugin system, that should be like the one from spigot.

It should have a plugin.yml inside.

I could open the jar with ZipFile and the load the Main Class but I have to load all classes.

But how should I make this ?

Comment: Use URLClassLoader.

Comment: This should help me. Thanks

Comment: And you can load the `plugin.yml` using `clasdLoader.getResource()`.